Split Azure DevOps user story to backlog instead of next sprint
On the Sprint board in Azure DevOps, a Split option is available for use on a user story at the end of a sprint to create a copy of the story and assign it to the following sprint along with existing associated tasks that aren't closed. This action leaves behind, in the sprint that's ending, the original story along with the tasks that were closed under it.
But we may decide that the remaining tasks are low priority and want to put them in the backlog. Is there a way to split the story with the copy going straight to the backlog instead of the next sprint? That is, instead of having to split to the next sprint, then navigate to the next sprint and move the new copy of the story to the backlog manually.

Are you perhaps using the Split! extension? I don't think Azure DevOps has a "Split" option by default.
AFAIK the extension only allows splitting to the next sprint, but I advise you to post your question here, as the devs seem open to suggestions. You could also look into implementing this feature yourself.
Another suggestion would be to split your user stories on priority during refinement.

I've now read that elsewhere as well. I don't know how they have our DevOps implementation put together, but it does seem that it has to be this add-on or another. Thanks for the lead.
